# Android Java - saving EditText's text when user presses "back"

Tags: android, android-edittext, gettext

I need to fill form and by pressing "Back" button save it , let's say, to preferences.
Or even show it to Log.

The problem is when I use `onBackPressed()` - Activity goes to `onPause()` and `myEditText.getText().toString()` returns result from XML and not the result that was actually in `myEditText` field. Same thing goes for `onDestroy()`.

Of course, if I hang `someButton.onClickListener()` it saves my data well from `myEditText` because Activity doesn't go `onPause()` and doesn't take result from XML, but I need to save it exactly by pressing back button.

The code is basic:

```
    EditText etCompetitionName;
Competition competition;
etCompetitionName=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.etCompetitionName);
 Intent intent=getIntent();//I get number of object to work with
pos=intent.getIntExtra("pos", -1); // this is this number
  competition=getObject(pos);// well, this is loading this object
 olDetCompetitionName=competition.getName();//getting name from loaded object
          etCompetitionName.setText(olDetCompetitionName);//set this text to EditText field
...
then :

protected void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
//try to save

competition.setName(etCompetitionName.getText().toString());
        saveObject(competition);
}
```

So, it saves old value, the one I set in the beggining. If I don't set it - it will be taken from layout xml. It is issue of `onPause()` I need to avoid it.

Comment: Saving the edittext in `onPause()` works. What do you mean with "result from xml"? Also, please include relevant code in the question.

Comment: btw, you can save text while buttons pressing with TextWatcher.

Comment: laalto, I edited - here's my part of code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your question is quite confusing but if you override `onBackPressed()` you can get the data.

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed()
{
     String text = myEditText.getText().toString();
     // save text
     super.onBackPressed();
}
```

I know you said you did this but show how you are doing it if this doesn't work. This will put whatever the user has typed in the `text` variable then you can save it in `SharedPreferences` or wherever you want.

You can also do the same thing in `onPause()` if you want it to save if, say, something else comes in the foreground.

Comment: Don't try to save in `onDestroy()`. Use `onPause()` or `onBackPressed()` depending on your needs as I said in my post

Comment: I just tried both onDestroy, onBackPressed() - the result is same, I just experimented

Comment: And what exactly is the "result"?

Answer (score 0):

SecondActivity.Java -> I saved two edittext value in SharedPReference and called the MainActivity intent

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getApplicationContext());
    Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
    editor.putString("1", a.getText().toString());
    editor.putString("2", b.getText().toString());
    editor.commit();
    Intent i = new Intent(SecondActivity.this,MainActivity.class);
    SecondActivity.this.startActivity(i);
}
```

MainActivity.Java -> I have a button listener to show a Toast with values from the sharedpreference.

```
show.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            SharedPreferences pref= PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getApplicationContext());
            String  a = pref.getString("1", "") ;
            String b = pref.getString("2", "");
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),a+"  "+b, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    });
```